# direct sum of linear spans

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

I have a question regarding the direct sum of subspaces.

Assuming we have a 3-dimensional vector space V with the basis {b1.b2,b3}. Then we have V=Span({b1, b2, b3}).

Is it also true that V=Span(b1)⊕span(b2)⊕span(b3) = Span({b1,b2}) ⊕ Span(b3)?

Comment: What does ⊕ signify here?

Comment: oh yes sorry, its the direct sum of Lie algebras.

Comment: Sure, this is a straightforward application of the definition (and not directly related to Lie algebras)